# Squarespace remove drop down menu from main navigation with CSS

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, squarespace

I really like how the FAQ page/questions look on the site I'm building using Squarespace.  The only issue is that because of this structure, it also leads to a cumbersome drop down menu when you hover over the FAQ tab on the main navigation.

Here's a link: http://www.officialjerky.com/faq-1/

While it's certainly possible to set up anchored links in another FAQ page, I'm also sure there's a solution that will allow me to keep the structure of the page(s) and get rid of the drop down.  Perhaps a bit of custom CSS that could make the drop down invisible?

There was a similar help thread that asked how to change the spacing between the items in the drop down, and the custom CSS input solution was: .primary-nav .folder-links-wrapper li { line-height: 0em; }.

Any guidance or input is really helpful. Thanks.

Comment: set `display:none;` on the subnav CSS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's controlled by JS, so you may need a mini sledgehammer to override it. Try this in your CSS:

```
.subnav {display: none !important;}
```

Ideally, remove the script that is causing the behavior.

Regarding the + on small screens, on line 9865 of the stylesheet there is this:

```
#sidecarNav .folder label:before {
    content: '+';
    padding-right: .25em;
    width: .75em;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

You could either remove that code, or just add this to the stylesheet:

```
#sidecarNav .folder label:before {
    display:none !important;
}
```

Comment: My man! That did the trick perfectly on my desktop browser.  Gotta check it on ios and see if that works too.

Comment: On ios, the link function is disabled and it only toggles between the + and - with nothing populating.  May need to grit my teeth and go with a less appealing design until I can get to the script and remove it.

Comment: Oops, I missed that. I've updated my answer to include the removal of the `+` on small screens.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you so much.  When I add the additional #sidecar to the .subnav stylesheet script, it solves the + problem on ios but also brings back the drop down issue on desktop.  Any workaround you can think of?

Comment: Not sure quite what you have done, but make sure to keep the original line of code (with `display: none !important`).